# Where does the main nav code actually live?

Tags: magento-1.9

I am talking about the default theme (Madison Island) And Magento CE 1.9.

I want to know where the main navigation is being made.

I have found the following file using template hints:

```
app\design\frontend\rwd\default\template\page\html\header.phtml
```

Inside of it I 've found:

```
<div id="header-nav" class="skip-content">
      <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topMenu') ?>
</div>
```

But where is the `topMenu` code? Where does it live? I would also like to know if there is some common logic to finding code like this, as I am new to Magento .

Comment: Commenting, as it is not a direct answer to your question, but generic answer to all questions of the sort.

In this question, I have answered about a few of the quickest ways to find where specific block/template code is located, as opposed to raw layout.xml digging.

[finding the right template files/blocks](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/30278/magento-page-xml-main-content-block-have-no-template-file/30281#30281)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code block you found inside `header.phtml` file calls another file `topmenu.phtml` in the same folder to display the menu. However, you won't find any helpful html code inside that file as the whole menu bar is created inside the `Topmenu.php` file which is available inside `app/code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Html` folder.
I think you should probably understand the Magento's layout structure for finding common codes like this. Most of the time, Layout files will provide you clear understanding of where to look for any particular html part in your magento installation. You will find blocks that provide logic for representation and the phtml files that merely display that logic to frontend wrapped around some html tags.

P.S. Dig some layout XML.

Answer (score 0):

TopMenu is in `topmenu.phtml`.  In the base `magento 1.9.X`
from your `public_html` directory or magento install:

> app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/page/html/topmenu.phtml

Curiously enough, the menu code only works when called from `header.phtml`. Just try to use it from somewhere else and it does nothing at all.